# Facebook API: get total_videos_views for all videos of a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to retrieve only one field of the video_insights for all videos of a page. Currently i am only able to retreive all metrics, but this is so much data that it takes very long to load.

```
window.FB.api(
  `/${pageId}/videos/`, {limit: 200, fields: 'description,video_insights'},
  function(listResponse) {
    // handle resonse
  }
);
```

I would like to have something like this

```
window.FB.api(
  `/${pageId}/videos/`, {limit: 200, fields: 'description,video_insights', metric: 'total_video_views'},
  function(listResponse) {
    // handle resonse
  }
);
```

But it seems the metric parameter does not work on the page/videos edge. Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct request syntax should be

```
/{page-id}/videos?fields=description,video_insights.metric(total_video_views)
```

With your call, you can place that directly into the `fields` parameter values,

```
{limit: 200, fields: 'description,video_insights.metric(total_video_views)'}
```

More info on this syntax: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion